# Interact with Chrony using Unix Sockets in Python

Tags: python, unix-socket, chrony

I have a python application where I need to be able to dynamically add an NTP server to Chrony. From the command line I can do:

```
sudo chronyc add server time.google.com
```

My understanding is that chronyc interacts with /var/run/chrony/chronyd.sock to dynamically change chronyd. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mlichvar/chrony/blob/master/client.c) I think I should be doing something like:

```
import socket
client = socket.socket( socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
client.bind('/tmp/my_chrony_sock.sock')
client.connect('/var/run/chrony/chronyd.sock')
client.send(b'add server time.google.com\n')
data = client.recv(4096)
```

But that just hangs never receiving a response

Answer (score 1):

The Unix domain socket should be datagram, not stream. A bigger problem is that the protocol is binary. AFAIK there is no python library implementing it.

You can capture the request with `tcpdump` on port 323 if you call `chronyc -h 127.0.0.1 add server time.google.com`. You can replay the request to the Unix domain socket. The hostname is at a fixed offset in a 256-byte field. Easy to modify.

Removing a source would be more difficult as it needs to be specified by IP address. You would need to implement the `chronyc sources` and `chronyc sourcename` parts of the protocol in order to find the address corresponding to the hostname.